# 記号の入力の仕方がわかりません。

Tags: python, python3, python-idle

[image: 独学プログラマーという本の1ページです。]

stagesのリストの中のハングマンの書き方がわかりません。具体的には　| と　0 が縦に揃わないことや右端の　", が縦に揃わない　これらの操作は手動でやるものですか？
ほんとに初歩的な質問ですみません。スラッシュもわからないです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"______       ",
"|            ",
"|     |      ",
"|     O      ",
"|    /|\     ",
"|    / \     ",
"|            "
```

空白の個数は適当ですがおおよそこんな感じです。ポイントは

- 環境によって、バックスラッシュは円記号として[表示される](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%86%86%E8%A8%98%E5%8F%B7#Unicode%E3%81%8C%E6%8C%81%E3%81%A4%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%EF%BC%88%E5%86%86%E8%A8%98%E5%8F%B7%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%EF%BC%89)。打つ際も、キーボードに円記号が書かれているキーを打つことでしか直接入力できない場合がある。
- 空白は全角スペースではなく半角スペースを用いるべき。幅を揃えやすくするため。
- 顔の部分はゼロより大文字のオーの方が良さそう。ゼロの場合、丸に斜線を入れるフォントがあるので。
- エディタやターミナルでずれて表示される場合は、[等幅フォント](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%AD%89%E5%B9%85%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88)を使うと良い。

Comment: nekketsuuuさん回答ありがとうございます。参考にしてやってみます。